# RelataiveLayout positioning

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout

Im trying to achieve a layout using Android XML Layout template:

[Layout Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDz7O.jpg)

I have XML currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/schedule_row_paddingtop">


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_row_teamLogoHeight"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="6dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/teamALogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/france_logo"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/programmeSport"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="sport"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/home_row_league_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/programmeTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/programmeSport"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="programme title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dip"
            android:textSize="@dimen/home_row_programmeTitle"

            />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/programmeDay"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2:30 PM"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="@dimen/home_row_date"
            android:layout_below="@+id/programmeTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/home_row_teamLogoHeight"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingTop="6dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/teamBLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/italy_logo"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

At the moment it does not look great as there is some overlapping going on, and on larger screens the "Team A Logo" and "Team B Logo" float off (as intended to be floating on the left and right side of the text) to the edges of the screen leaving a huge game besides the text in the middle:

[Sample output of the issue in Android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4MU6.jpg)

I need the images which float on the left and right to be in the same position vertically for each fixture and for them to be inline with the "TeamA v TeamB" horizontally.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should follow either ConstraintLayout or LinearLayout in order to achieve your desired output.
You can do something like the below.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/teamALogo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_team_a_logo"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/teamALogo"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/teamBLogo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/teamBLogo"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/teamBLogo"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="League"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Team A"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vs"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Team B"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/teamBLogo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_team_b_logo"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```